# Is there any way for a Visual Studio addin to be using custom command line arguments?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, command-line-arguments, visual-studio-addins

I want to know if it's possible for a custom addin to reach out for custom command line arguments passed to devenv.exe. Is it? I can't seem to find anything on Google. Thanks.

Comment: @downvoter, would you mind explaining what's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible.  You can read the command line arguments using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` but the add-in can't extend the set of arguments that can be passed.

In general extensions in Visual Studio read extra information via registry settings or environment variables instead of command line arguments